# SharePont 2013 Lightbox for Picture Library

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, picture-library, responsive

Anyone who can help implement the lightbox plugin to a sharepoint picture library.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use Client Side Rendering (CSR) to built your own HTML, and wack on http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/#examples

Comment: Thank you for the response. Do u mind elaborating more on this solution. I am used to using this solution on HTML5 and I'm struggling on SharePoint. How do I reference my images that are on the library?

Comment: You need to learn CSR.. search for SharePoint+CSR.. it is the sharepoint way of adding JavaScript to pages... and Check out the Cisar Chrome plugin for live editting

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to this: link http://www.amrein.com/apps/page.asp?Q=5740.

You can use Lightbox webpart for your requirement. Deploy the wsp, configure the webpart on the page where the picture gallery is to be displayed. All details of installation and Configuration is present in the link.

Comment: Thank you Ankitkumar, I am looking for a free solution without having to buy solutions based on existing free platform like lightbox and prettyphoto